# How to do browser mining without being a jerk?

Tags: cryptocurrency

**Context**

Of all the ways to make my website (in my case the website runs calculations on the user's games and outputs graphs of it) financially viable, I figured mining would theoretically be one of the least invasive, while still being profitable enough for me.
By mining, I mean that there's a script running on the end users' browser, only using cpu power, that mines cryptocurrencies for my wallet.

**Question**

How to make that process as non threatening as possible for my users?

Should I give them another option? Should I give out rewards associated with it, or on the contrary be as concise as possible about it?
Or am I wrong to think it could be a win-win to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure it's legal, but I am pretty sure it's unethical...

Comment: Actually, just thought of this - is the mining happening only while the user is running the application, or constantly while the user's computer is operating?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing isn't new, it's just the crypto part that is. Users have long been consenting to [grid computing](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=1410682), allowing third parties to run background scripts in the name of donating their CPU power for good causes.

So I think *consent* and *awareness* are the key to doing this ethically. You might offer a free level and a paid level for your application. If the user chooses the free level, the mining is explained to them. They opt into it with the option of being able to opt out later (reverting to whatever happens when there's no revenue for you - basic trial level? No access?)